# run-time design in FMX?

Tags: delphi, runtime, firemonkey, form-editing

There are components that let you edit forms at run-time in VCL.

Is run-time editing of forms possible in FMX? (I want the ability to modify forms inside of mobile apps.)

Comment: Clearly it's possible, as that's exactly what the IDE does. If I post that as an answer, will you accept it as useful? If not, then improve your question to be more specific than "is it possible".

Comment: Sorry, if I ask what I want to ask, it'll be downvoted and locked. Get creative. ;-)  (It is so infuriating not being able to ask for suggestions for stuff anywhere, since the Embt forums have become virtually useless and you cannot ask speculative questions here in an attempt to learn about stuff you don't know about in general.) ... in fact, I see it has already gotten votes to close it down. How in the dickens can anybody expect to learn about component libraries when sites like this prohibit you asking about them? How does that help boost Delphi use?

Comment: SO isn't about *boosting Delphi use*. This site has guidelines which are explained pretty clearly in the [help]. Asking for recommendations (for components or anything else off-site) is covered specifically in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/on-topic); see the section with the numbered list in it. If you want those guidelines changed, post a request in [meta]. Be advised, though - the topic has been asked about multiple times and rejected. You might check the guidelines at [softwarerecs.se] to see if it fits there; they're quite strict, so check the help first.

Comment: Yeah, so where do people go to ask about what components or libraries are available to do certain things? Clearly not SO. (or is that prohibited info as well?)  ... I have not been able to post a question to Embt's Delphi forums for days; they've been down for most of today already. There's no place I can find to post questions like this, and nobody really seems to think that lack of access to product suggestions and recommendations is a problem.

Comment: The fact that SO has policies like this doesn't make them right. It just makes them socially acceptable. Like if everybody agreed that racism is ok in some city. I disagree, but from all I can tell, the "community" prefers to prohibit these kinds of questions. Telling people to bring it up in the Meta group after countless others have been unable to make a difference is really not helpful.

Comment: My last comment offered both a suggestion for a site where you *might* be able to ask your real question, and info on what you should do if you have a request for the guidelines to be changed here. [meta] is the only place to ask for changes or make feature requests; it's *specifically* what it's designed to do.  Arguing with me (or anyone else) about it in comments isn't going to get you anywhere. If you don't like the guidelines here, you have two choices: 1) request to get them changed at [meta], or 2) find somewhere other than SO to ask your question.

Comment: In the many years SO has been around and the myriad of requests about this issue of recommendations, I seriously doubt I have anything to add that's any different from anybody else. Why it should be prohibited to simply ask people to identify components and/or libraries that can (or might) accomplish something specific in a forum full of people who know that stuff is beyond me. Google is useless for these kinds of queries. And the vendor's site has been equally useless for a year now. How do people find such answers? Also, I don't see StackExchange as any more useful.

Comment: The topic has been discussed **at length** previously at [meta]. **Take any further discussion of the subject there where it belongs.** Discussing it here is pointless, and you're flogging a dead horse. **If you want to ask for a change, do so at [meta]. If you just want to complain, take it to [meta].**  The discussion **does not belong here in comments**. The **only place** in all of [se] where you can possibly ask for a recommendation is at [softwarerecs.se] (if it meets their guidelines), period.

Comment: Your question is off topic here. You are asking for component recommendations. Please don't argue that here MSO is where to make that argument. This question will be welcomed over on the Google+ delphi developers group.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, do you mean editing on device from with an app (e.g. for end users) or editing from a remote device (e.g. designing forms 'live' on the target device)? All you need is a replacement for the IDE's designer. My defunct MonkeyStyler product had one for FMX styles but, of course, those are basically the same as forms. The code never made it past XE2/XE3 and is buggy on recent editions. You can contact me via http://monkeystyler.com if it's off topic here.

Comment: There are components that let you do this in VCL. I'm simply asking if there are any that let you do that in FMX. Unfortunately, for reasons that make absolutely no sense to me, it's inappropropriate to ask that question here. You have to go somewhere that has fewer experts. All this bellyaching about this nonsense policy is pathetic. I'm won't post anything further in this thread, or Meta. I tried to delete the question, but because there's a (nonsense) answer, I cannot. I've asked the mods to delete it, but it's still here. I guess people love to see this crap instead of useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question first: Yes it is possible to modify FMX forms and its controls at run time.
For your second question: AFAIK there are no components that would you help with that task.
If you want to go and make your own form designer, be aware that the seemingly highly suitable TSelection component is very buggy up until XE7 and still has some flaws in XE 8 - you better make your own.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, exactly as in VCL, but most object property will be different.
Following sample create new Button on main form.

```
unit ufmMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TfmMain = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    MyButton1: TButton;
  end;

var
  fmMain: TfmMain;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TfmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyButton1 := TButton.Create(fmMain);
  MyButton1.Parent := fmMain;
  MyButton1.Position.X := 10;
  MyButton1.Position.Y := 10;
  MyButton1.Width := 50;
  MyButton1.Height := 10;
  MyButton1.Text := 'TEXT';
end;

end.
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask how to create objects at run-time.

Comment: OK. Then answer to your question -- NO, you cannot EDIT FORM in already compiled application. Under EDIT -- i mean exactly the same way as you using in IDE. It's not possible even in VCL. It's not possible even in ... any other technology/programming language.

Comment: in time of Turbo Vision for Turbo Pascal 7 was additional editor/tool, that give you ability to design forms, but still without ability to modify already compiled form.

Comment: Zam, you're wrong. You *can* modify a form in an already compiled application using the VCL and the Windows API. DFM files are stored as a binary resource of type RCDATA. You can load that resource, alter it, and update it in the executable file using `UpdateResource` (look it up on MSDN) and it's related functions.

Comment: @KenWhite -- but can you do this while program is running? i suppose no

Comment: You can allow the user to move controls around all you want, and you can persist that to your own file (the Classes unit contains the code to do so). The next time the program runs, it streams in that binary content and creates a form (again, the Classes unit has the code already). Voila! You've modified a form at runtime. It's precisely what the IDE does when you're designing a form in the IDE, and it's precisely the purpose for the DFM file. There are even VCL libraries that you can buy that do all of this for you. The question asked here was if there is such a library for FMX as well.

Comment: so you need "JV Runtime designer" but for FMX.